# graph-tool graph_draw plot a colorbar legend

Tags: python, graph-tool

So I have a graph and I draw this graph to a PDF using this command:

```
graph_draw(G_Sub, vertex_fill_color=pr, vertex_size=prop_to_size(pr, mi
    ...: =5, ma=15), vorder=pr, vcmap=matplotlib.cm.gist_heat, output="G_Sub_pr.
    ...: pdf", vertex_text=G_Sub.vp['name'], vertex_font_size=0.5)
```

Now, I want the colorbar used to generate node colors to be plotted next to the graph. Is there a way to do this in graph-tool?

Answer (score 3):

No, graph-tool does only graph visualization, it is not a full fledged plotting library. For that, there is matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html

Comment: But is there a way to plot the graph-tool graph using matplotlib?